# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on submit

Tags: php, forms, exception, laravel-5

I litteraly started to use Laravel for the first time 3 hours ago and I'm trying to create a basic golden book where people can write some good things about a restaurant.

So I created my controller with the command `php artisan make:controller GoldenbookController --resource`, then my model with the command `php artisan make:model Goldenbook -m`. In the migration, I simply added "name" and "message" before migrating. I also added the `resource` inside the `routes/web.php` file

After creating the view and the form, I tried it and got the following error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218
```

I saw a lot of people having this issue, but the way to solve it doesn't match my case since I use `Route::resource` to tell Laravel my CRUD.

Here is my **GoldenBookController.php**

```
 /**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('goldenbook.create');

}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nom' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ]);


    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $goldenbook = new Goldenbook;
    $goldenbook->nom = $request->name;
    $goldenbook->message = $request->message;
    $goldenbook->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Here is my **form**

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'goldenbook/create']) !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('message', 'Message') }}
    {{ Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Save', null,['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And here is my route file, **web.php**

```
Route::resource('goldenbook', 'GoldenbookController');
```

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Route::resource('livre-dor', 'GoldenbookController');` should be `Route::resource('goldenbook', 'GoldenbookController');`

Comment: This is a typo, I tried several things before asking for some more help here, but changing 'livre-dor' for goldenbook didn't change anything

Comment: I see. Another thing: `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'goldenbook/create']) !!}` should just be `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'goldenbook']) !!} ` as the route controller will automatically call the `store` function for a POST to that resource. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the routes in both `web.php` and your `form`.

Your `web.php` should have the word `goldenbook`

```
Route::resource('goldenbook', 'GoldenbookController');
```

And your form should have the routes as `goldenbook/store` or `goldenbook`

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'goldenbook/store']) !!}
```

Or you could also pass the name of the route too.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'goldenbook.store']) !!}]
```

This should solve your issue.

If you want to know the name of your routes and is using `Laravel 5.*` you could use

```
 php artisan route:list
```

to check whether your url matches to the route or not.

You are hitting the wrong route to use the `POST` method as your `goldenbook/create` route accepts only `GET` requests. This should solve your issue.